# Unable To Read ApplicationSettings from Web.Config

Tags: web-config, appsettings

I have searched all over and I can't seem to get this one solved.

All I am trying to do is read application settings from the web.config.

I found an article here - but that isn't working.

my code:

```
return System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName];
```

My Web Config does indeed have settings:

```
  <setting name="AirmetDataCacheExpiration" serializeAs="String">
    <value>5</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="MetarDataCacheExpiration" serializeAs="String">
    <value>5</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="TafDataCacheExpiration" serializeAs="String">
    <value>5</value>
  </setting>
```

My hunch is this is something to do with the web.config in my VS solution and the machine.config...

So how do I make sure I am reading the right one?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060993/differences-in-behavior-between-system-web-configuration-webconfigurationmanager

Comment: Just tried it.  Now I get an error:  Error 67 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: I've always used `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name]` to access appsettings in web.config. have you tried that?

Comment: That's what I had originally.  I just tried again - no luck.  It's got me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251998/system-configuration-configurationmanager-does-not-work-in-visual-studio-designe) link helped steer me on the right path.

```
So instead of using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager["appsetting"]
```

You use this:

```
(string)Properties.Settings.Default[settingName].ToString();
```